# Why does the splash look different on every device?

Tags: android, statusbar, launch

`AndroidManifest`

```
    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".login.SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
   
        </activity>
```

`style.xml`

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@mipmap/splash</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

`@mipmap/splash` is just a image.

This is my AppTheme and SplashActivity theme.

I build the same code in several device but has different results.

Some devices show the app icon before launch.
Some devices statusbar is transpraent, some devices are not.

Why does the splash look different on every device?
Can't this kind of thing be made simpler?

Answer (score 0):

To my experience, there are a few things that affect how a splash screen looks on an Android device:

- Phone Manufacturer: Samsung, Motorola, Sony all apply their modified Android version where usually, the default themes and activity animations provided by the framework are overridden. To get a unified experience on the splash screen activity startup animation, you need to [hardcode those animations](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/transitions/start-activity#custom-trans) in the `styles.xml` file, otherwise the Android default animations are applied.
- Android Device API: Some theme modifications only are available for specific API versions. For example, the [status bar coloring option](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)) was introduced with API21 together with the [option to color the navigation bar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setNavigationBarColor(int)). Also, the look of the [dark theme](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/darktheme) was changed starting with API29.
- Android Device Hardware: This might be a trivial aspect, but when your app is executed on a fast device, it might happen that your splash screen is not visible at all. In your example, the background mipmap will be overlaid by the actual activity content.

Note at this point that Google introduced a dedicated [Splash Screen API](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen) with Android 12, which allows even more different customizations, like animated app icons. With this standardized API we can hope in the future though that the splash screen might look the same across all the devices.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest. I will try to implement Splash api.

Answer (score 0):

May be default splash screen is messing with your splash activity , try adding `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` to your splash theme , maybe it will solve,

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but still not works :( .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).